# Slippery slope facts of spherical and plane object

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics, friction

Imagine a slippery slope and from the top of the slope I threw two object one is spherical stone and the other is plane box. Why the stone would reach the bottom by rolling randomly where the box would reach sliding?

Comment: It's not clear what your question is. Are you asking why a cube does not roll down a slope when you let go of it? (What force should make it turn over its edges?)

Comment: Yeah and why a spherical object do so as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although your question isn't posed very clearly I worked on the problem of non-spherical objects sliding/tumbling down a slope and don't mind sharing the following insight with you.

[image: Ball and cube on slope.]

Left, a cuboid and right, a sphere of comparable dimensions and mass. The inclination has been chosen deliberately high.

Let's look at the forces and torques acting on both objects.

$mg$ acts on $C$ and $C'$. But immediately it becomes clear that in the cuboid's case $mg$ also causes *torque* about the point $P$. This causes acceleration about $P$, as per Newton, and means the cuboid with topple over. So tumbling is to be expected here.

By decomposing $mg$ as shown in the force diagrams we obtain the Normal force acting perpendicularly to the slope. Simple friction models state that the friction force, shown in light blue, is *proportional* to that Normal force. Of course it also depends on the 'slipperiness' of the slope's surface.

In the case of the cuboid, whether or not slipping will occur will depend on whether the $mg$-component that is *parallel* to the slope is greater than the friction force or not.

In the case of the sphere, the friction force causes a torque about $C'$, causing the sphere to start rotating. Whether the sphere will roll *with or without* slipping will depend on the 'slipperiness' of the slope's surface.

Note also that as the incline is steeper, tumbling with slipping will be favoured for the cuboid, while sliding without rolling will be favoured for the sphere.

'Flatter' cuboids will also be less prone to tumbling, as the torque caused by $mg$ tends to become negative at some 'flatness'. In fact for a perfect cuboid one can see the inclination has to be at least $\frac{\pi}{4}$ ($45\:\text{degrees}$) for tumbling to be even possible.

Comment: Sir but usually the cuboid doesn't tumble. But why if the slope is steeper the cuboid will tumble and the sphere won't tumble but will slide?

Comment: At high inclination, $mg$ 'falls' to the right of $P$, at lower inclination to the left of it. Sphere's don't tumble, they roll. Unless of course they *bounce* but I'm not throwing the objects down.

Comment: Okay what about the sphere sir why it may not roll if the slope is steeper? Sir u said ""while sliding without rolling will be favoured for the sphere."".

Comment: As long as there is *some* friction it will always roll. But if friction is insufficient it may *roll AND slide* at the same time. But that's quite a hard calculation, actually. The steeper the incline, the smaller the Normal force and thus the smaller the friction force. Less torque, less rolling and more sliding.

Comment: Sir just a bit. does rolling and sliding have a difference.?

Comment: Full rolling means rotation with translation. Full sliding means translating without rotation. (translating means linear motion).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42917/discussion-between-ffahim-and-gert).

Comment: Having dinner now, maybe later?

Comment: Sir pls answer that why torque is produced on p and why on C'?

Comment: Firstly, do you understand what *torque* (syn. couple, moment) is?

Comment: @Gert : If we initially provide a ball with some friction and then remove friction, a ball will still roll over due to its inertia.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel: You're correct but did I say otherwise? :-) If you launch a rotating ball on a very slippery surface it will *continue* rotating. But we don't really call that rolling.

Comment: @Gert +1, it was fine. I was reacting to comment. I had not read full answer :P. OP asked me to look at question. I found answer good after reading first few lines. It was quite long you know.